# How to use dynamic linq when using inheritance (TPH) in the entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

1. I am creating an expression builder or query builder to query one specific Entity.
   The entity is called RequestBase, this entity has some properties, but there are 3 other entities that inherit from Request Base.
2. Because I am using TPH, then only one table is created with a discriminator column and all other properties are created in the RequestBase table.
3. The problem is when using Dynamic LINQ to query on a property which is not in the RequestBase entity but on the childs.

** **Code for Request Base** **

```
public class RequestBase
    {
        public int RequestBaseId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
        public string RequestNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsOnHold { get; set; }

        public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
        public virtual Requester Requester { get; set; }
        public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<WorkflowHistory> WorkflowHistories { get; set; }

}
```

** **Code for EcoBonusRequest** **

```
public class EcoBonusRequest : RequestBase
    {
        public string BrandReturnedVehicle { get; set; }

        public string TypeReturnedVehicle { get; set; }

        public string ChassisReturnedVehicle { get; set; }

        public string DestructionCertificateNumberReturnedVehicle { get; set; }

        public decimal AmmountWithVAT { get; set; }

        public decimal AmmountWithoutVAT { get; set; }

        public decimal Percentage { get; set; }

        public DateTime VehicleDesctructionDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

** **Code for querybuilder** **

```
private string BuildQuery()
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                //var list = RequestBaseBL.GetRequestByCustomQuery("RequestNumber == \"12\"");

                #region 1st ROW of the QUERY
                if (ColumnType(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue) == "Text")
                {
                    if(DdlOperator1.SelectedValue == "==")
                    {
                        sb.Append(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue);
                        sb.Append(DdlOperator1.SelectedValue);
                        sb.Append("\"" + TxtValue1.Text + "\"");
                    }
                    if (DdlOperator1.SelectedValue == "<>")
                    {
                        sb.Append(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue);
                        sb.Append(DdlOperator1.SelectedValue);
                        sb.Append("\"" + TxtValue1.Text + "\"");
                    }
                    if (DdlOperator1.SelectedValue == "LIKE")
                    {
                        sb.Append(string.Format("{0}.Contains(\"{1}\")", DdlColumn1.SelectedValue, TxtValue1.Text));
                    }
                    if (DdlOperator1.SelectedValue == "NOT LIKE")
                    {
                        sb.Append(string.Format("!{0}.Contains(\"{1}\")", DdlColumn1.SelectedValue, TxtValue1.Text));
                    }
                }

                if (ColumnType(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue) == "Number")
                {
                    sb.Append(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue);
                    sb.Append(DdlOperator1.SelectedValue);
                    sb.Append(TxtValue1.Text);
                }

                if (ColumnType(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue) == "Date")
                {
                    sb.Append(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue);
                    sb.Append(DdlOperator1.SelectedValue);
                    sb.Append(TxtValue1.Text);
                }

                if (ColumnType(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue) == "Bool")
                {
                    sb.Append(DdlColumn1.SelectedValue);
                    sb.Append(DdlOperator1.SelectedValue);
                    sb.Append(TxtValue1.Text);
                }

                #endregion  


                return sb.ToString();
            }

        #endregion
```

** **Generated sql that should be executed** **

```
public IQueryable<RequestBase> GetRequestByCustomQuery(string strql)
            {
                return _context.RequestBases.Where(strql);
            }

? sb.ToString()
"AmmountWithVat=1"
```

** **Error** **

> No property or field 'AmmountWithVat' exists in type 'RequestBase'

Comment: this might be helpful as well. maybe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829128/dynamic-linq-how-to-generate-like-and-not-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would work:

```
    public IQueryable<RequestBase> GetRequestByCustomQuery(string strql)
    {
         return _context
               .RequestBases
               .OfType<EcoBonusRequest>()   //
               .Where(strql);
    }
```

You can easily adapt this function:

```
    public IQueryable<T> GetRequestByCustomQuery<T>(string strql)
        where T :  RequestBase
    {
         return _context
               .RequestBases
               .OfType<T>()   //
               .Where(strql);
    }
```

So the issue is how to get that type there in BuildQuery(). Not easy, but that's how you set it up.

Comment: What about if we have other child objects that inherit from RequestBase?

Comment: That's what I meant with "not so easy". You'll have to keep track which type(s) belong to which property.